# program that encrypts messages using Caesar’s cipher

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

I have been having this error in my code. it works fine but immediately after the 8th character in my input in `plaintext` its like the formula goes wrong or something just changes in the calculation and its starts encrypting into the wrong characters.
**Please can someone help me figure out what i did wrong?**

I already tried using the debugger, but i couldn't understand what was wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char upperciphertext (char text);
char lowerciphertext(char text);

int key;
char cyphertext[] = "ciphertext: ";


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //check if command line arg. is inputed and not more than 1
    if (argc > 2 || argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    //check if characters are digits
    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
        //convert commandline argument to int
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
    
    key = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    char * plaintext = get_string("plaintext: \n");
    
    //loop to iterate over each character in text
    for (int i=0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        //turn uppercase letters to uppercase ciphertext
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) && isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            char cytext = upperciphertext(plaintext[i]);
            strncat(cyphertext, &cytext, 1);
        }
        
        //turn lowercase letters to lowercase ciphertext
        else if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) && islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            char lowcytext = lowerciphertext(plaintext[i]);
            strncat(cyphertext, &lowcytext, 1);
        }
        
        else
        {
            strncat(cyphertext, &plaintext[i], 1);
        }
        
    }
    printf("%s\n", cyphertext);
    
}



//function to cipher uppercase characters
char upperciphertext (char text)
{
    int alphaindex, cipher, ciphertext;
    char ctext;
    
    alphaindex = text - 65;
    cipher = (alphaindex + key) % 26;
    ciphertext = cipher + 65;
    ctext = ciphertext;
    return ctext;
}

//function to cipher lowercase characters
char lowerciphertext(char text)
{
    int alphaindex, cipher, ciphertext;
    char ctext;
    
    alphaindex = text - 97;
    cipher = (alphaindex + key) % 26;
    ciphertext = cipher + 97;
    ctext = ciphertext;
    return ctext;
}
```

Comment: What do you get when printing `plaintext[i]` after the `for (int i=0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)` loop ?

Comment: i get the exact text or character i inputed

Comment: Hi, you might want to read this article first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. After that ask questions about the part of C that surprised you. Don't frent there are some chunks of C that I find scary till this day.

Comment: Look at `char cyphertext[] = "ciphertext: ";`: how much room you imagine has been reserved for the array `cyphertext[]`? Where you expect will be writter, or best overwritten, the text that you are adding with `strncat(cyphertext, &cytext, 1);`?

Answer (score 1):

`char cyphertext[] = "ciphertext: ";` defines `cyphertext` to be just large enough to hold `"ciphertext: "`, and `strncat` appends to the end but does not increase the allocated space. So your program writes outside the space allocated for the array, corrupting memory used for other purposes.

You must provide sufficient memory for `strncat` to have room to append characters. Make the array larger or use some other allocated buffer to work in.